# If there is a linear map from V to W where the dimension of W is greater than V, how to you map the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are problems in linear algebra where the proofs go like

> Suppose we have $\dim V \leq \dim W$. Since $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, there exist a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$. Define a linear map $T:V \to W$ by $$T(a_1v_1+ \dots +a_nv_n) = a_1w_1+ \dots +a_mw_m + \dots. $$

The part I don't understand is how you can map each basis element of $V$ to a basis element of $W$ when $W$ has a higher dimension than $V$. For example, let $\dim V = 3$ and $\dim W = 4$, then $v_1$ maps to $w_1$, $v_2$ maps to $w_2$, and so on, but what about $w_4$?

Comment: each basis element of $V$ gets mapped to an element of $W$, which can be expressed as a linear combination of basis elements of $W$, but the images of basis elements of $V$ cannot comprise a basis of $W$ because of its higher dimension

Comment: ok that makes sense

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: after some further reading it makes sense now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Each basis element $v_i\in V$ gets mapped to an element $w_i\in W$, and each $w_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of basis elements of $W$, but the images of the basis elements of $V$ cannot comprise a basis of $W$, because the dimension of $W$ is higher.